# Configuring Database in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring-boot

I am trying to configure mysql database in spring boot. But I can't seem to do so. I am new at this so I have no idea what I am doing. I have tried searching. Please help what am I missing:

applicatiomn.properties:

```
  ## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
     spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     spring.jpa.show-sql=true
  spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users_database? 
   useSSL=false
 spring.datasource.username = sa
 spring.datasource.password = root


 ## Hibernate Properties
 # The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

 # Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

 info.app.name=Spring Boot - RestTemplate CRUD Rest Client Example
 info.app.description=Spring Boot - RestTemplate CRUD Rest Client Example
 info.app.version=1.0.0

 server.servlet.context-path=/springboot-crud-rest
```

Here my username and password is correct. How to configure my url?

Also, I have added the required dependencies in my pom.xml file as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>net.guides.springboot2</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot2-jpa-crud-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springboot2-jpa-crud-example</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


 </project>
```

Error: [image]

Please help what am I missing?

Comment: add spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Please check my updated question @codeogeek I have these added in my file already

Comment: what error do you get? paste the error instead of the image, it's cropped on the right, so I can't see all the information

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the property `spring.datasource.driverClassName` or `spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName`. You need to set it to an implementation for Hikari. It is also worth checking if the driver exists in your classpath. I did not see it in your list of maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have these properties added in my application.properties. It is still giving me the error. Let me update my question to attach a picture of the error.

Comment: I have added the dependency but the error still remains. Please check my updated question

Comment: The stacktrace in the image is entirely different to the stacktrace provided in the main post.

Comment: The stacktrace says Error starting tomcat context. Can you  help? @jason